# Error in SSRS subscrition but not in Report Builber or ReportServer WebUI

Tags: sql, reporting-services

So I have this report using a stored procedure which runs as expected in ReportBuilder and also on demand in the Report Server WebUI (or export as PDF).

However, when the report is generated by the subscription of the said report, it halts in error:

```
ERROR: Error occurred processing subscription 4ff1b786-ec4f-4d23-8cfa-a341f43ca78e: Failure writing file M04_IBM_CDS_DSTS_PledgeCollateralAndLoanItemsRecon : The Hidden expression for the tablix ‘Tablix1’ contains an error: The expression references the field 'CATEGORY', which does not exist in the Fields collection. Expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope. Letters in the names of fields must use the correct case.
```

I've tried,

- Recreate the subscription
- Recreate the report from scratch
- Use a different version of ReportBuilder
- Used various credentials for the datasource
- Made sure the stored proc was actually working

I'm absolutely clueless as to what could make it fail as a subscription but not by other means. Any idea where to start to troubleshoot this issue??

I am on SQL server 2008

**EDIT**: im actually on SQL2014...
**EDIT**: It works if the subscription is generating a Word rather than a PDF... this obviously a SSRS bug

Comment: Is there any difference in the build profiles? I.E. Dev / Build versions.

Comment: I would check to see if the `CATEGORY` field is in the correct case. Some generators will ignore the issue while others will fail. You may have changed it in the dataset but not the **Hidden** expression for Tablix1.

Comment: Yes, case is the same (all caps for both).

Comment: @Gareth I'm not sure I understand your question

Comment: I think Gareth means if the version of SSRS is different between your report server and your Visual Studio. I don't think that would be the right issue if the subscription server is the same as the Report Server that it does run on. The only other thing I can think to check is the dataset of the table. The error message usually gives a fairly good idea of the problem - there's **some** issue with that expression's field.

Comment: The reportbuilder is for 2014. The later version simply wont save to SSRS. And VS is 2015 with the latest BI tools.

Comment: I honestly doubt the tools have anything to do since the report generates fine in the ReportBuilder webUI...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the ReportServer was in an erroneous state and the issue resolved itself on it's own over the weekend. 
I'm guessing one the IT automated task which restarts the server solve the issue.

No trace in any logs as to what happened really.